# JQuery/CSS Events/Animations for one page bootstrap design. (on Click & On scroll)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

Im interested in creating animations as the user either clicks or scrolls through my page. **(its important that animations trigger on both clicking the links in the navigation and scrolling)** I am currently using a bootstrap bare bones template (one page scroll). 
I have included the Javascript that was initially in the files for the on click scroll event.

```
$(function() {
$('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated as Im pretty much lost when it comes to this! I managed to create an on load fade in effect in pure CSS on the landing page. I would love to continue to use pure CSS throughout if possible.

I have managed to create a fade in effect on the about page using the javascript below the problem is that when i click the about link again the text disappears. I would like for the text to remain after the user clicks the about link and is taken to that section of the page.

```
$(function() {  
$("#btn").click(function() {  
$(".box2").toggleClass("box2-change");  

});  

});
```

For further reference here is the download/demo for the template Im using.
http://startbootstrap.com/scrolling-nav

Comment: Could the `html` and `css` be posted? Thanks.

Comment: Create a fiddle so it is easy to help you

Comment: Here is a link that includes my site. https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/808111186e4c496dc8acfd4df20fe4d320140324010640/820c51c5db571c1b4abfc93620ddf90320140324010640/08a84f

Comment: Are you opposed to using a jQuery plugin to do this?

[Panel Snap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/)

Answer (score 0):

// inside document ready

```
$("#yourElement").on('click', doStuff);
$("#yourElement").on('scroll', doStuff);
```

// later in the .js file

```
function doStuff()
{
  // triggers both the click and scroll event

}
```